# Inherited ASP.NET MVC2 solution; server errors being rendered as garbage text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have inherited an ASP.NET MVC2/VS2010 solution from a previous developer. In playing around with it I quickly realized that any and all server errors are not being displayed as such. They seem to be getting consumed and then a bunch of garbage text appears on the screen.

I'm not sure how this was managed, or where to even start looking for something like this. Has anyone experienced this before that could offer some insight into where to start looking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC errors are often caught using the HandleErrorAttribute.  This can be apply at the controller or action level.  The fact that you're seeing garbage has me a little concerned as normally this attribute generates a generic error view (which you can customize).  I wonder if you've got content type mismatches with some AJAX code -- you might want to use Firefox with Firebug or the IE developer tools to catch the requests in flight and see the request/response headers and response content.

Comment: I just tried loading the page under IE9 with the Dev Tools window visible. I was prompted with "Do you want to open or save Index (12.9 KB) from localhost?" 

Inside of the Developer Tools I went to Script -> Start Debugging and all of the source immediately turned to garabage chars.